# What API's provide Nokia for Sound to text and text to sound transformation?

Tags: java, audio, speech-recognition, nokia

What API's provide Nokia for Sound to text and text to sound transformation for Java or C++ programmer?

What do I need?

- Links to best API's of your choise
- Links to best Blog Articles/Tutorials on topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the S60 handsets at least there is built in text-to-speech. Have a look at [this article](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Text_to_speech_in_Symbian_2nd_and_3rd_edition_phones) which details the 'low quality' API, and [this article](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/KIS000843_-_Binary_compatibility_break_in_Text-To-Speech_Utility_API) which points to the higher quality API.

Not aware of it being accessible from MIDP in Nokia handsets, and I believe speech-to-text isn't open to third party developers. (There is a MIDP JSR, JSR-113, for speech but I don't know of any devices which support it.

I've not had any experience of third party libraries.